# Q&A: Is it possible to mint many tokens by single call?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, ethereum-classic, mint

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

I was curios about options we have to mint a token. Is it possible to mint many tokens by single call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amount of tokens for minting might be extended from one to many, but there is a limit of gas to be used defined in ethereum ledger which brings natural boundaries on how many tokens could be minted at once.

3rd party solutions for similar task https://metasender.co/

> In one transaction:
>
> To mint one item, use _mint(...).
>
> To mint up to 20 items, use _mint(...) in a for-loop.
>
> To mint up to 500 items, use the "ghost minting" technique. Please see
> the Area NFT contract for an open source example of that. Note this is
> an advanced technique that will surely require customization based on
> your application.
>
> To mint enough tokens to track ownership of nanobots a few micron in
> size and in aggregate totaling half the size of Earth, use the "lazy
> array" technique. Please see the Su Squares contract for an open
> source example of that. This is only possible at the time of contract
> deployment.

> The _safeMint(...) function makes the recipient of a token, if it's a
> contract, get a onERC721Received(...) call. This functionality is not
> required by the standard and you may have some specific reason you
> want to use that.
>
> You can only create N tokens at once efficiently during contract
> creation
>
> Don't be afraid of creating contracts to create tokens
>
> Contracts can be created efficiently using the proxy standard

> By William Entriken